# How to load servlet as first page in jsp application manage other servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, anchor, web.xml

I wanted to load a servlet as the first page in my simple jsp appication. Therefore I added the servlet in this URL mapping.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StudentController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.stu.controller.StudentController</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StudentController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And this is the Get method of above mentioned servlet.

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        if (path.equals("/addstudent")) {
            createStudent(request, response);
            ......
        else {
            searchAll(request, response);
        }
     }     

    protected void searchAll(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<StudentDTO> coList = null;
        coList = StudentDAO.searchStudentList();
        if (coList != null) {
           request.setAttribute("stulist", coList);
        } else {
           request.setAttribute("msg", "No Record Found.");
        }
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
   }
```

This is working as predicted, but the problem is I tried to create another servlet called *CourseController* and I mapped it in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CourseController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.stu.controller.CourseController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CourseController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/course/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the Get of the servlet is same as before.

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        if (path.equals("/addcourse")) {
            createCourse(request, response);
            ......
     }
```

And I tried to access the servlet using an anchor tag in my *home.jsp* page.

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/newstudent">Create Student</a> 
<br/>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/course/newcourse/">Create Course</a>
```

But I keep getting 404 error while trying to connect *CourseController servlet*.

[image: error message]

This some how return to the searchAll method in StudentController servlet. I understand something is wrong with the mapping here. But I don't know what is that.

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure unique url-patterns, so "/" cannot work if you have more than one servlet.

Assuming that your first servlet has url-pattern "/newstudent" you can configure it as welcome-file:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>newstudent</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: I do not know what anchor tags are.

Comment: Sorry, so how can I access those method in controller? like `newcourse`?

Comment: I do not understand your question. You first asked about path mapping, now you wan to access a method. Which method do you want to access from where and why?

Comment: So sorry my mistake. Thank you for your anwer.

Comment: The correct answer is to replace `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` by `<url-pattern></url-pattern>`. See the duplicates.

Comment: @BalusC I tried that before and then I got 404 for both paths.